# Selecting multiple tables in Slick form

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I have two tables - Item and Category. I would like to be able to specify in an itemForm available in the View that I want to select Category from(as Item will have a FK into the Category table).

Rephrased: At the View level, I want to have a set of inputs generally mapping to `Item`, and for the `Category` FK, I want to have a dropdown populated by the Category table.

The view right now is:

```
  @form(routes.ItemController.save) {
      @inputText(itemForm("name"))
      @inputText(itemForm("description"))
      @inputText(itemForm("category"))
      @inputText(itemForm("date_acquired"))
```

Note that category right now (as written) requires an integer. Which is very anti-user - which I want to avoid!

For the model -

```
class Items(tag: Tag) extends
    Table[Item](tag, "Items") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey,  O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name",  O.NotNull)
  def description = column[String]("description",  O.NotNull)
  def category_fk_id = column[Int]("category_fk_id")
  def date_acquired = column[org.joda.time.DateTime]("date_acquired",  O.NotNull)
  def sponsoring_member = column[String]("sponsoring_member",  O.NotNull)

  def * = (id.?, name, description, category_fk_id, date_acquired, sponsoring_member) <>
    (Item.tupled, Item.unapply)
}
```

Then the itemForm in the controller -

```
object ItemController extends Controller {
  val itemForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> optional(number),
      "name" -> text,
      "description" -> text,
      "category" -> number,
      "date_acquired" -> jodaDate,
      "sponsoring_member" -> text)(Item.apply)(Item.unapply))

// Some functions here
```

So - the question - how do I set up a Form that can read/write on multiple tables?

Comment: How about writing a wrapper case class that wraps an Item and a Category and an associated factory method that can be used with the Form? Then the controller needs to take the items out of the case class and write them to the db.

Comment: Look up nested forms in the docs, you want to wrap your single form in a Seq, and then map your query result as a Seq[Entity]. In the end you have a Seq[T] result that you bind to a Seq[Form[T]]